# Mysql : How can i replace a part of a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string

I want to delete everything after "x" in the following urls :

i have :

```
url
/product/dtphdmi230rx?subtype=384
/product/dtphdmi230tx?subtype=385
/product/dtphdmi330rx?subtype=386
/product/dtphdmi330tx?subtype=387
```

i want :

```
url
/product/dtphdmi230rx
/product/dtphdmi230tx
/product/dtphdmi330rx
/product/dtphdmi330tx
```

I know it's easy with mysql 8.0 with `regex_replace` but i can't update my server. Is there any way with mysql 5 ?

nb : There is always a "?" in urls, it can be the first character to delete.

Thanks for help

Comment: if the part before `?` is always the same lenght you could simply use `LEFT(..)` or `SUBSTRING(..)` functions in MySQL..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
left(url, locate('x?', url))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29e682e8770b9b9829bb197e1ee44abb)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select '/product/dtphdmi230rx?subtype=384' url
    union all select '/product/dtphdmi230tx?subtype=385'
    union all select '/product/dtphdmi330rx?subtype=386'
    union all select '/product/dtphdmi330tx?subtype=387'
)
select left(url, locate('x?', url)) from mytable
```

```
| left(url, locate('x?', url)) |
| :--------------------------- |
| /product/dtphdmi230rx        |
| /product/dtphdmi230tx        |
| /product/dtphdmi330rx        |
| /product/dtphdmi330tx        |
```

---

Note: as commented by Raymond Nijland, if the `?` occurs just once in the string and can be used as the first character to remove, you can also do:

```
left(url, locate('?', url) - 1)
```

Comment: You could simply do `locate('?'` instead  ?  As `?` can only be used  once in a URL?

Comment: *" if the ? occurs just one in the string, you can also do:"* i wasn't totally clear with mine last comment.. i meant The URL specs saids that `?` can only be used once in a URL It is used to indicate where dynamic params starting for a dynamic script..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: clear enough! I updated my answer accordingly, thanks!